# Disable javascript code in media queries

Tags: javascript, jquery, media-queries, responsive

I want to know how can I disable a bunch of JavaScript code when different media queries and which one is the best way to do that.

I use to create and delete a script tag from body in specific size, it works but the problem is in big size when the functions run and variable set it remains in DOM though the tag is not exist in small queries.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  if($(window).width()>=768){
    mainJs();
  }
  $(window).resize(function () {
    if ($(window).width() >= 768) {
      if (!$('head script[src="_assets/main.js"]').length)
        mainJs();
    }else{
      $('head script[src="_assets/main.js"]').remove();
    }
  });
  function mainJs() {
    var elm = document.createElement("script");
    elm.setAttribute("src","_assets/main.js");
    elm.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(elm);
  }
});
```

I have a interval in my main js file and with resize some time it hanged and run multiple of times because the previous one remain in DOM.

Comment: You can't disable JavaScript by removing the script tag. You should disable parts of functionality by making it part of your logic flow. Respond to events and update the state of your application accordingly.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just have one script and check for the window width in the relevant functions? Media queries are meant for css, not js. To remvoe all of the relevant parts of the script, you'll have to 'null' all of the variables and functions involved. Have a look at your full design and ask yourself 'why am I trying to remove pieces of script'.

Comment: [`matchMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) is more flexible ([usage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Testing_media_queries))

Comment: Javascript cannot be removed based on media query. Try creating a DOM that works on media query and other DOM which works on normal web view and as per your media query Dom can be prioritize.